# Trying to invoke an AWS sagemaker endpoint for a locally trained Object detection model (with .pb file). Facing this issue while invoking

Tags: docker, tensorflow, object-detection, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a multi model endpoint and facing issue while invoking the object detection model alone. The OD model has only .pb file and no variables folder in the saved model dir. While trying to invoke the endpoint with a sample image, I am getting this error:
[Error in Cloudwatch:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4I3v.png)